# On iPad Pro, does some apps stay full screen even when working in a 2 app side-by-side mode?

Tags: ios, ipad, multitasking

Because Pokemon Go has a bug on the iPad version and I cannot see the number of Pokeballs remaining to catch a Raid Boss (due to aspect ratio of iPad about 4:3, not the same as iPhone's 16:9), so I want to use the 2-app-side-by-side method to see if I can somehow change the aspect ratio of the app.

So I either run Pokemon Go and slide in a Safari, or run the Safari and slide in Pokemon Go.  (By running Pokemon Go, and then slide from bottom up of the screen to see the dock, and then touch-and-hold an app and move it to the edge of the main screen area).

Either case, I see Pokemon Go running as a full screen app.  Is it true? Some apps cannot run as a side-by-side app but must remain full screen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true. The app must be compatible to run side-by-side - and if the app is not, there's nothing users can do about it other than encourage the developers to add the support.

Comment: so in a way it is not "black box"... meaning that the app can't be running in an environment that the iOS provides.  If it is a black box, then an app doesn't need to be specially made into able to run side-by-side, but is just made into displaying in that given region (such as by iOS resizing the window to fit into the side-by-side panel)

Comment: Your statement does not really make sense. No one is claiming that apps are "black boxes" - nor is being a black box a requirement for running in an environment the OS provides. And even if it were a "black box", apps still would need to be created so that they support multiple view port sizes in order for that to work. The reality of this is that there's a property list inside each and every apps on your iOS device. When trying to side-by-side an app, iOS will check if this property list contains a key that tells that the developer okays side-by-side usage. If it is not there, it won't work.

Comment: what you are saying is poor software design. If it is good design, it should be able to run in any reasonable screen size just by resizing. Given a square region that is 768 x 768 on the iPad, if the app runs well full screen on an iPad, then just resize this app to be 768 x 3 / 4 : 768, which is 576 x 768. Doing so is really simple in the OS, and it allows all the full screen apps to run in any region without needing any special change.

Comment: It is your opinion that it is poor software design. I do not agree with your opinion. It reasonable to allow the developer of the app to decide if their app is designed to be run simultaneously with other apps and at a different view port size. The app developer can then decide if that is a good user experience, or if they want that not to happen to avoid user's having difficulties due to these circumstances.

Comment: if the OS is robust enough, it should allow simply running of an app in a certain dimension in another different environment. iPhone-only apps being able to run on iPad with the iPad showing it in the iPhone aspect ratio and with everything running perfectly is a good example and is good design. Why you don't agree with good design is beyond comprehension.

Comment: You definition of "good design" is entirely subjective. It hasn't got anything to do with the robustness of the OS. There's definitely a tradeoff involved when you want to run a program on a different device with a different view port size than intended. I think it makes good sense to let the developer decide whether or not he thinks the apps work sufficiently well to allow that. If you do not agree with that decision, it hasn't got anything to do with robustness or "poor design". It is just your opinion.

Comment: I have been in software industry for 30 years. How about you? You are almost proposing if the monitor size is not 1024 x 768, the app should not work unless it is full screen, and the OS, seeing the monitor is 2560 x 1440, should not fit the 1024 x 768 window to be inside the monitor and make it part of the desktop and that it has to be full screen

Comment: Similar time. You're making nonsensical straw man arguments which are really not fruitful. To sum this up - Apple has decided that the app developer decides how his app is displayed for the customer. I think that is reasonable. You think this means that Apple creates poor software and non-robust systems. That's your opinion.

Comment: How is that mine is "opinion" and your statement "you are ... nonsensical", "your statement does not make sense" not opinion and you make it sound like universal truth? You are purely superior? Because of what?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to pick a fight instead of having your question answered. Do that in the chats with someone else.

Comment: You are the person who come into the discussion with somebody you never met, and outright said, "Your statement does not really make sense." I bet you are welcomed by a lot of people in real world and I won't waste any time on you any more

Comment: If I had to meet with everyone on Stackoverflow before I could try to answer their questions, I doubt that we would get much done. You seem to be taking everything very personally - it would probably be productive for you to leave that habit behind.